# why is my dsfml code not compiling through dub

Tags: d, sfml, dub

I tried to compile dsfml using `dub` by i keep getting this error:

```
Linking...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-window
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-system
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-audio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-network
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-graphics
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
FAIL .dub/build/application-debug-linux.posix-x86-dmd_2067-FDAB6DCF10EB7D29BC4DAB2CF2FAFD5C/ dsfmlapps executable
Error executing command build:
dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

I made sure I installed both sfml and csmfl on my Ubuntu (14.04 32bit) through the repository. Any idea what is the problem?

Edit: here is my `dub.json` file

```
{
    "name": "dsfmlapps",
    "description": "A minimal D application.",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2015, karabuta",
    "authors": ["karabuta"],
    "lflags" : ["-L/usr/include"],
    "dependencies": {
        "dsfml": "~master"    
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried and failed to figure this out, but here are some things I noticed: 1. I needed to link to `csfml-*`, not `dsfml-*`. 2. It seems to be referencing a number of symbols I don't see in the SFML API (e.g.  `sfFont_getTexturePtr`). I've not familiar with SFML however.

Comment: show your `dub.json`. And sfml/csfml not needed. Did you read [this](https://github.com/Jebbs/DSFML/wiki/Getting-Started-in-Linux)?

Comment: Do you maybe need the sfml DEV headers? I know thats one of my most common linker error mistakes...

Comment: Missing library files.

Comment: Did you placed files from the archive ([32bit](http://jebbs.github.io/DSFML/bins/linux/DSFML-Current-Linux32.zip) / [64bit](http://jebbs.github.io/DSFML/bins/linux/DSFML-Current-Linux64.zip)) to your `/usr/include` directory?

Comment: No I did that to see if it will work, but it doesn't work whether I place `lflags` in the `dub.json` or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in the `dub.json` from DSMFL. It contains specification of libraries in the form: `"libs": [ "dsfml-audio" ]`. But `"libs"` specifies an external library found somewhere else! The name here is `dsfml-audio` but if you look in the build directory from DSFML then you will see that the library file is named `libdsfml_audio`. (Note `-` versus `_` in the name.)

Solution is to remove all `"libs": [ "..." ],` lines from the `dub.json` file. Use `dub -v` to check the referenced files!